# Pulling an audio file into a PHP script and auto-tuning it?

Tags: php, audio

I want to write a PHP script that can programatically grab a .wav file from a URL, auto-tune it, and then either save it as a new file or output it using an "audio/x-wav" header, but I don't even know where to start.  Are there audio manipulation libraries in PHP that can accomplish that?

Comment: Wow! That sounds like a huge, almost impossible, task. I'm not even sure there is open source "auto tuning" software. Auto Tune by Antares and Melodyne by Celemony are both high end commercial products. Not to mention the massive amount of variables there would be: eg. key of the song, vibrato, amount to tune etc etc. This will be interesting to see :D

Answer (score 2):

1. [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or [sockets](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) for downloading
2. [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) + [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) for editing
3. [header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) + [readfile](https://www.php.net/readfile) for sending to user

Comment: This won't autotune a file though. You'll need a filter for ffmpeg.

Comment: @Josh: sure he has to get a filter. I did not said that my 3 items list is a magic that will do all the work for him ;-)